# jpa mapped superclass without id

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance

I'm curious about the following problem. I've two entites, `A` and `B`. It stores almost the same information (for example, a name - in real life it's more complex), but the joins, and the foreign keys differs.

Can I do a mapped superclass, without an Id. And `class A` and `class B`, extending the mapped superclass, containing only the Id attribute?

For example:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
@Data
class superClass {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@Data
class A extends superClass {

    @Id
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "referencedName")
    private SomeClass id;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
@Data
class B extends superClass {

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "referencedName")
    private SomeOtherClass id;

}
```

Would it be valid by the JPA? I did read the `mappedSuperClass`'s JavaDocs, and says nothing about it. I would said, that it is valid - but the IntelliJ Idea says, that the super class has to have an Id attribute. I didn't find anything on the internet about this.

edit: sorry, I missed it. I left the `Entity` annotation on the superClass, and that's why the Idea signed the error. I removed that, and the error disappeared. But I'm not sure, that this is valid, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is valid. Anyway your superclass will not appear as a table in the DB.

Answer (score 3):

yes, there is no requirement that a MappedSuperclass have anything in it. It is just providing extra annotations for the subclasses.